# How to merge and split numpy array along the axis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge, split

I have the data in the following form the shape of the array is

```
   (10,4,4,3)
```

First i want to create an array with shape (merging, or flattening)

```
  (10,48)
```

such that data (4,4,3) is converted to one row.

Secondly I want to go back to the original shape of the data(splitting) such that each element is again placed at the same location.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
b = a.reshape(10,48)
a = b.reshape(10,4,4,3)
```

Comment: And the first one will also work letting numpy do the math as `.reshape(10, -1)`.